# Firebase Functions emulator lost connection to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a setup, where I can emulate my Cloud Functions locally and they access my Firestore database. It used, to work well for development and testing, but recently it has lost connection to the Firestore database.

I was wondering if anyone else have had this problem or have an idea, how to fix it?

Since I don't understand, what changed, here's a list of things I tried and observed:

1. I have updated firebase-tools, firebase-admin and firebase-functions
   to latest versions
2. I store my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a
   json file on my computer and running `firebase emulators:start`
   starts the server up and serves my functions just fine.
3. But, when the functions request the database, it doesn't throw errors, but
   simply return empty result sets.
4. If I add new documents to the database in a
   function and then query the collection in same function, I get the
   newly created documents. So this make me think, that I have landed
   in some sort of testing mode?

Sorry about the lack of code, but I don't really know where to start in of these "it used to be working" situations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently now

```
firebase emulators:start
```

...will silently NOT connect you to the real Firestore database anymore, because it emulates the Firestore database. If you run

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

..it connects to the Firestore according to the credentials provided.
I'm not sure when this behavior was introduced, but hopefully this helps others experiencing the same.

I am now running latest versions:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
```